# Изменение контейнера на основании выбранного пункта select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется список `select`. Как сделать так, чтобы к `<div class="content">` при выбранном значении `table` добавлялся класс `column`, а при значении `line` - удалялся?

HTML:

```
<div class="block-sort-item">
    <span>Показывать записи:</span> 
    <select id="news-view">
        <option data-class="table">Столбцом</option>
        <option data-class="line">В линию</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="content column">content</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Добавляем обработчик события `change` элементу `#news-view`.
- Внутри обработчика берём `data-class` у выбранного пункта и в зависимости от его значения добавляем или удаляем класс `column` у `.content`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $container = $('.content');
    $('#news-view').on('change', function () {
        var selectedClass = $(this).find(':selected').data('class');
        $container.toggleClass('column', selectedClass != 'line');
    });
});
```

```css
.column {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-sort-item">
    <span>Показывать записи:</span> 
    <select id="news-view">
        <option data-class="table">Столбцом</option>
        <option data-class="line">В линию</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="content column">content</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Код работает, но не совсем так, как нужно. Имеется такой select 
                <div class="block-sort-item">
                    <span>Показывать записи:</span>
                    <select id="news-view">
                        <option data-class="table">Столбцом</option>
                        <option data-class="line">В линию</option>
                    <select>
                </div> как сделать так, что бы к <div class="content"></div> при значении table добавлялся класс column, а при значении line происходил removeClass('column')

Comment: Я думал есть какой то универсальный код) Вот ссылка на фидл http://jsfiddle.net/8n59t7dy/

Comment: Благодарю) код работает

Comment: @Димон на здоровье.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно этот код привязать к кукам?

Comment: @Димон если возникает проблема с работой с cookie, вы можете задать новый вопрос, **подробно** описав что требуется, как пытались решить проблему и что не получилось.